# Extend model get/build method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to update my person object every time i retrieve it from the database and then save it again .. But how to do it?

My object, Person, with a bool-attribute seen_by_organization which is 0 when its created.
First time the Person is retrieve from the database i want to set the seen_by_organization to 1.

Ive tried put into the constructor, but it seems not to work

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    if($this->seen_by_organization == 0)
    {
        $this->seen_by_organization = 1;
        $this->save();
    }
}
```

I know a method to bind code to "on save", but not "before get" or "after get".

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    //This is on saving
    static::saving(function($model)
    {

    });

    //Is there something like this ? 
    static::getting(function($model)
    {

    }
}
```

I hope that you can help me

Thanks !

Comment: Is there something like this ? - Yes there's a event-driven architecture

Comment: Yeah - but what is the name of the event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in event for this. Also `created` is not the one you need - it is fired when a new model is inserted to the storage.

You need something like this:

```
// This is called after fetching data from db
// override it in order to fire the event you need
public function setRawAttributes(array $attributes, $sync = false)
{
    parent::setRawAttributes($attributes, $sync);

    $this->fireModelEvent('loaded', false);
}

// add handler for new event
public static function loaded($callback)
{
    static::registerModelEvent('loaded', $callback);
}

// do the job
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::loaded(function ($user) {
       if($user->exists && $user->seen_by_organization == 0)
       {
         $user->seen_by_organization = 1;
         $user->save();
       }
    });
}
```

Mind that it will be called for each model that you retrieve using `get()` or `first()` etc. so there might be multiple `inserts`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it !

The name of the event is created

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function($model)
    {
        if($model->seen_by_organization == 0)
        {
            $model->seen_by_organization = 1;
            $model->save();
        }
    });
}
```